# Checking keystore file in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-keystore

I've changed my pc and reinstalled Android Studio as well as my old project.
I've copied my old keystore files in the following directory
"C:\Users\MyUserName.android"

But when I run the program it looks like the keystore is not recognized(not connecting to google services and so forth...)

How do I check if my keystore file is working properly?

Answer (score 1):

There are two keystore files usually used.  One for debugging and one for doing release builds of your apps you plan to upload to an app store.  The debugging keystores can be generated anytime, so, it doesn't hurt to create a new one in your new IDE setup.  But for your release keystore, you will want to build a new version release of your app and export it, then try to upload it to your App Store.  If there is anything wrong with the signing, the App Store should reject it.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to generate signed apk . If you got error than you keystore is not setup. If it generate then it's okk.